# Encoding all characters for jQuery ajax call. Having issues with ampersand not storing in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax script set up to store data in a textarea. I want the textarea to accept all characters. How can I encode the text to include `&` as a character, and not as a $_POST element in PHP.

PHP FILE

```
$data = stripslashes(  $_POST['t5t'] );
echo $data;
```

Javascript File

```
function save_form(formdata) {
        var encoded = formdata;
        $("#results1").text("Javascript:\n"+encoded);

    //  var encoded = encodeURIComponent(formdata); // testing encoding
    //  var encoded = $('<div/>').text(formdata).html(); // testing encoding

        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-content/plugins/secret/process.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "t5t="+encoded,
            processData: false,
        //  contentType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#t5t #save img').css('opacity','1');
                $('#saved').css('color','#DBDB0B');
                $('#saved').text('Saving');
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#saved').text('Saved!');
                $('#saved').css('color','#0BDB2C');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#saved').css('color','#fcfcfc');
                    $('#t5t #save img').css('opacity','.25');
                }, 500);
                $("#results2").text("PHP:\n"+data);
            },
            error:function(data){
                $('#saved').css('color','#DB0B0B');
                $('#saved').text('Error');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#saved').css('color','#fcfcfc');
                    $('#t5t #save img').css('opacity','.25');
                }, 2500);
                $("#results2").text("Error saving. Contact support if you require assistance. Error: "+data.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Javascript Before Sending as POST:

```
{"task1":"// &lt;a href='/' id=\"id\" target=\"_blank\"&gt; &lt;? &lt;&gt; ~!@#$%^*()_+|}{\\][\":';? &gt;&lt;/.,&amp;&lt;/a&gt;\r\n","task2":"","task3":"","task4":"","task5":""}
```

PHP Processed after receiving as  POST:

```
{"task1":"// <a href='/' id=\"id\" target=\"_blank\"> <? <> ~!@#$%^*()_ |}{\\][\":';? ></.,
```

Actual string I'm trying to store (to try and break the system and find flaws)

```
// <a href='/' id="id" target="_blank"> <? <> ~!@#$%^*()_+|}{\][":';? ></.,&</a>
```

Comment: [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Wow, it looks like I may have had it right with `encodeURIComponent(formdata)` as it seems to work now. Anyone confirm that everything is correct, and I should use `encodeURIComponent(formdata)`?

Comment: No, that data is automatically encoded, you can look whats sent over the line with a tool like firebug (a plugin for firefox that you can install). chrome also have such a tool. You open those with F12 and look in the network tab.

Comment: How do you call `save_form()`? Where does its parameter come from?